# PropertyChanged is not attached

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, dependency-properties

I've got a visual control in WPF, which takes advantage of dependency properties. These properties are backed by fields, which are classes, and sometimes there's a need to notify all bindings, that value of property changed, when actually the contained class was modified.

Simply said:

- MyDepProp is of type MyClass;
- The contents of MyClass changes due to control's internal operations;
- I want to inform everyone, that MyDepProp changed, such that they can reflect to changes in MyClass.

MSDN says, that PropertyChanged is attached to DependencyObject, when the dependency property is used for the first time. And it works in Visual Studio 2010. However, after installing Visual Studio 2012, it stopped working: even though the DP was used (eg. binding was attached to it), PropertyChanged is null and I cannot inform anyone of changes.

I still use Visual Studio 2010 compiler toolkit, so It seems, that it's a matter of broken framework, which was updated along with VS 2012.

Do I use the PropertyChanged event correctly? Or is it a bug in .NET 4.0 framework updated by VS 2012? Have anyone encountered similar problem?

---

**Edit:** A piece of buggy code:

```
public partial class MyImageControl : INotifyPropertyChanged,
    IHandle<ImageRefresh>
{
    // ***************************
    // *** Dependency property ***
    // ***************************

    private void OnDataSourceChanged()
    {
        // ...
    }

    private static void DataSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is MyImageControl)
            ((MyImageControl)d).OnDataSourceChanged();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DataSource",
        typeof(IDataSource),
        typeof(MyImageControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, DataSourceChanged));

    public IDataSource DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (IDataSource)GetValue(DataSourceProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetCurrentValue(DataSourceProperty, value);
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DataSource"));
        }
    }

    // ***********************************
    // *** INotifyPropertyChanged impl ***
    // ***********************************

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // *************************************
    // *** Method, which exposes the bug ***
    // *************************************

    public void Handle(ImageRefresh message)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BackgroundKind"));
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DataSource"));
    }
}
```

For reference, the IHandle interface:

```
public interface IBaseHandle { }

public interface IHandle<TMessage> : IBaseHandle
{
    void Handle(TMessage message);
}
```

**The scenario:**

- DataSource *is* bound to another property using the `Binding`
- Someone calls `Handle` method of the control (using the `IHandle` interface)
- Handle checks, whether PropertyChanged is not null and it is, so no information about changes in DataSource are propagated.

Comment: Can you show some code, it's all working fine in VS2012 at my pc...

Comment: This might be hard, it's actually a part of a huge project and in many places this mechanism works. This is why I cannot easily provide a proff-of-concept code. If I manage to do so, I'll post it here. That's why I asked, if anyone encountered this problem too :)

Comment: I'm using DPs in VS2012 at the moment without any problems. Make sure you have one instance of the datacontext otherwise you could be updating the wrong one. Also ensure that RaisePropertyChanged event is called with the same name as the property. Without code those would be the first things I'd check.

Comment: It seems, that this problem persists in many more places. I've modified my question and included a piece of source code cut from the project. Please take into consideration the configuration. Project uses **.NET 4.0**, is compiled in **VS 2012**, using the **VS 2010** compiler toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

First, this code is redundant:

```
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DataSource"));
```

It's not recommended to write any additional code in usual property setter because WPF DP system accesses DPs directly without using setters or getters.
Raise `PropertyChanged` in `OnDataSourceChanged` method.

Second, your control inherits `DependencyObject` what allows you add Dependecny Properties.
There is a chance that update changed the former behavior and DP system now does not subscribe to notifications via ProprtyChanged event when binding to Dependency Property of the control because there is no need for it. DP system has its on notifications.
That could be the reason why `PropertyChanged` is null.

**UPDATE**

I think that setting CurrentValue as you do can lead to subtle bugs. Usually `SetCurrentValue()` is used when value should be changed due some internal reasons. E.g. `TextBox` sets its `Text` property value with `SetCurrentValue()` when user types text. This allows to save bindings.
But what will happen if you try to set bindings programmatically?

According to what you told in the comments you can try:

- Set value to null and then back.
- Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for DataSource
- Call `DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty()`

Comment: If so, how can I solve the problem, eg. notify about changes inside the DataSource property? And if PropertyChanged is not set in deterministic way, how can it be useful? I got an impression, that if class implements INotifyPropertyChanged, the PropertyChanged handler is guaranteed to be set.

Comment: Note, that setter calls `SetCurrentValue`, not `SetValue`. The first one does not propagate informations about changes in the DP, AFAIK.

Comment: Both propagate but SetCurrent... does not override value source.
Well, why do you need to notify if there were no real changes of the property? And if they are then DP system will notify the subscribers.

Comment: Because the value of DP didn't changed, but the value of the value of DP changed :) I mean: DP still holds the same class, but the class contents changed and others may be interested in updating in result of these changes.

Comment: Oh, now I see. First hack is to set DP to null and then back to former value, the second one is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for DataSource itself, I mean types.

Comment: Bingo! Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.supportschangeevents.aspx I think this appears to be the reason. Check this property. It should be true because you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. May be some new parameter was added which affects the whole result.

Comment: Thanks for your info, I'll investigate that.